# Checking if ALL form inputs are filled with Jquery and do something

Tags: jquery

I want to hide the submit button and show it only if all inputs of my form are filled in with values.

I try this but it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $fields = $("#new_account_form :text, :file, :checkbox, select, textarea");
    $fields.keyup(function() {
        var $emptyFields = $fields.filter(function() {

            // remove the $.trim if whitespace is counted as filled
            return $.trim(this.value) === "";
        });

        if (!$emptyFields.length) {
           $('#submitAccount').show();
        } else {
            $('#submitAccount').hide();
        }
    });
});?
</script>
```

Comment: Does it work if you add quotes to the selector for the element you're trying to hide and show, right now you have syntax errors.

Comment: No this is not the problem.... in my code there are quotes

Comment: please post your html code, its hard to determine what went wrong without knowing what you worked on

Comment: It should be noted that checking if the value of a checkbox etc. is an empty string probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: From a user experience perspective, it is recommended to disable the button, and enable it when applicable, then it is to start with no button at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. The below one shown is for validating all the dropdown and text controls in the form. Similarly you need to iterate for all `checkboxes` and other controls and set `count` value accordingly.

```
function validateInputs() {
  var count = 0;

   // for all dropdowns with class as .dropdown
   $('.dropDown').each(function (index, item) {
      var selectedValue = $("option:selected", $(this)).val();
      if (selectedValue == "0" || $(this).find('option').length <= 1) {
         count = 1;
         $(this).css('border-color', '#ff0000'); // optional if you want to change the border color to indicate a required field
     }
   }, 0);

    // for all textbox in the page
    $('form input[type="text"]').each(function (index, item) {
      if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
        count = 1;
        $(this).css('border-color', '#ff0000'); // optional if you want to change the border color to indicate a required field
      }
     }, 0);

  if (count == 1) {
      $('#submitAccount').hide();
  }
  else {
      $('#submitAccount').show();
  }
}
```

and you can call the function to validate all form inputs from `$(document).ready`

```
$(function () {
   validateInputs ();
});
```